# Select language for text-to-speed on android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, text-to-speech

I have searching for many hours without a real answer.

Is there anyway to select different language than the default one for the Text-to-speech function?

This code works perfectly on chrome on PC, but not working on Android browser:

```js
$(function(){
  if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
    speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
      var $voicelist = $('#voices');

      if($voicelist.find('option').length == 0) {
        speechSynthesis.getVoices().forEach(function(voice, index) {
          console.log(voice);
          var $option = $('<option>')
          .val(index)
          .html(voice.name + (voice.default ? ' (default)' :''));

          $voicelist.append($option);
        });

        $voicelist.material_select();
      }
    }

    $('#speak').click(function(){
      var text = $('#message').val();
      var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
      var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
      msg.voice = voices[$('#voices').val()];
      msg.rate = $('#rate').val() / 10;
      msg.pitch = $('#pitch').val();
      msg.text = text;

      msg.onend = function(e) {
        console.log('Finished in ' + event.elapsedTime + ' seconds.');
      };

      console.log(speechSynthesis);

      speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
    })
  } else {
    $('#modal1').openModal();
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.95.1/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="col s12">
          <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Text to speech example</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <form class="col s8 offset-s2">
    <div class="row">
      <label>Choose voice</label>
      <select id="voices"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s6">
        <label>Rate</label>
        <p class="range-field">
          <input type="range" id="rate" min="1" max="100" value="10" />
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col s6">
        <label>Pitch</label>
        <p class="range-field">
          <input type="range" id="pitch" min="0" max="2" value="1" />
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12">
        <p>N.B. Rate and Pitch only work with native voice.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <textarea id="message" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
        <label>Write message</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="speak" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Speak</a>
  </form>  
</div>

<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <h4>Speech Synthesis not supported</h4>
  <p>Your browser does not support speech synthesis.</p>
  <p>We recommend you use Google Chrome.</p>
  <div class="action-bar">
    <a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-green btn-flat modal-action modal-close">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.95.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks a lot!!
Greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after search and search finally I found the solution and it´s very very simple...

In PC Chrome, the lang of the voice goes implicit in the voice packet but in Mobile Chrome the lang must be specified explicit in the SpeechSynthesisUtterance object.

So for the example it works adding the line

```
  msg.lang = voices[$('#voices').val()].lang;
```

If someone needs help, I'm ready.

Greetings.